# Automatic quiz selfgrading websolution

Tags: google-forms

I need a quiz for my students:

I have tried working with googleforms, using "super quiz" and "flubaroo". The problem with the two plugins, was that it did not send the email automatically.
Then i made a script to do that, but the problem here is the students don't have the permission (and i can't provide it). I tried to change the permission in googleform, did not work.

It should work something like this:
1. Student answer questions and submit the answer.
2. Student automatically receives a graded version and should be able to see their wrong answers. 
3. Teacher receives the same version as nr 2.

Is there some kinda multiplechoice that does this? This should be easy and I assume im not the first one that want this solution.

Comment: [Moodle](https://moodle.com/) can provide that kind of functionality. But I'm not sure this is the right place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using google form and flubaroo.